# Is the order of the product of an infinite order element and finite order element always infinite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let G be an abelian group, and let g, h ∈ G. Show that, if g has infinite
order and h has finite order, then gh has infinite order.

I was trying a proof by contradiction by letting (gh)^n = 1 so g^nh^n=1. But I don't know how to proceed/know if I am going down the right path. Am I going down the right path?

Comment: Well, so far, you haven’t used the order of $h$

Comment: Yes, but I'm not really sure how the order of h relates to the order of gh.

Comment: You don’t really need to know that there is any relationship.

Comment: we have g^n = h^-n. That implies that (g^n)^m = (h^-n)^m = 1, where m is is the order of h. This is a contradiction, hence proved. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $|h|=n$ and $|gh|=m$.
Then we have $$1=(gh)^m=g^mh^m\implies g^{-m}=h^m$$
Hence $|g^m|=|g^{-m}|=|h^m|=\frac{n}{(n,m)}$.
This is a contradiction because $|g|$ is infinite implies that $|g^m|$ is infinite.

Comment: You don’t need to be so fussy with the gcd, just use $1=(gh)^{mn}=g^{mn}$